# Azure SQL - default isolation level when using ADO.NET

Tags: azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database

In Azure SQL the default isolation level is RCSI. I understand the behaviour of this. What breaks it for me is, as I understand it, I need to use read committed when selecting my data through a simple ADO.NET SqlConnection. I have difficulty understanding if row versioning is applied when doing a simple select. What is the default isolation level applied when using SqlConnection?

**EDIT**
From here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server#snapshot-isolation-level-extensions

I read

> The READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option determines the behavior of the default READ COMMITTED isolation level when snapshot isolation is enabled in a database. If you do not explicitly specify READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON, READ COMMITTED is applied to all implicit transactions. This produces the same behavior as setting READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF (the default). When READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF is in effect, the Database Engine uses shared locks to enforce the default isolation level. If you set the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option to ON, the database engine uses row versioning and snapshot isolation as the default, instead of using locks to protect the data.

Does this mean that the database just upgrades all default transactions to RCSI and thus it applies row versioning to everything if not a specific transaction level is specified? So SqlConnection just defaults to RCSI instead of the default read committed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure SQL Database default database wide setting is to enable read committed snapshot isolation (RCSI) by having both the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION database options set to ON. You cannot change the database default isolation level. However, you can control the isolation level explicitly on a connection. One way to do this, you can use any one of the following statements in Azure SQL Database before you BEGIN TRANSACTION:

```
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL  SERIALIZABLE
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL  SNAPSHOT
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL  REPEATABLE READ
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL  READ COMMITTED
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL  READ UNCOMMITTED
```

SET TRANSACTON ISOLATION LEVEL controls the locking and row versioning behavior of Transact-SQL statements issued by a connection to SQL Server and spans batches (GO statement). All of the above works exactly the same as SQL Server.

In addition, the above statement "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED" will set the isolation level to read committed snapshot isolation (RCSI). This isolation level is different from read committed (RC). In other words, the default behavior of “SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED" in on-premise SQL Server is RC, but in Azure SQL Database is RCSI. If you want to use exact RC (not RCSI) behavior in Azure SQL Database, you have to set the lock [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017) READCOMMITTEDLOCK to the SQL statement.

Comment: So by having RCSI enabled all transactions that was once were under read committed now is row versioned. I don't have to do anything in my code.

Comment: Everything runs RCSI by default and row versioning is in place. You don't have do anything. You can change that behavior with SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL when needed.